# MySQL Value of a field through a function

Tags: mysql, triggers

My goal is to insert value into a field through a function.

Following is the function, I created.

```
DELIMITER $$

create function Identifier(num int)
Returns int
Begin
Return (num*10);
end $$
DELIMITER ;
```

Following is the table

```
create table simulator
(
    id BIGINT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    identifier BIGINT null,
    name varchar(20) null,
    number varchar(30) null
);
```

Now my goal was to update the value of identifier depending upon the id, which is auto incremented. Eg: if the id was 1, the identifier would be 10, if 2 identifier would be 20.

I created a trigger that would set the value of identifier before inserting (I am a little confused between before/after insert).

Following is the trigger

```
CREATE TRIGGER before_insert_simulator
    BEFORE INSERT ON simulator
    FOR EACH ROW
        SET new.identifier = Identifier(new.id)
```

But everytime the value of identifier is 0.

I am running mysql 8.0.16

Comment: Which means auto_increment has not yet taken effect. (and please fix the syntax errors in your create table)

Comment: Updated the syntax for table creation, sorry for that. As auto_increment has not taken effect yet then how to tackle this situation?

Comment: Trigger cannot solve this task - when BEFORE INSERT trigger fires the AI value is not available yet.

Comment: So I should try with after insert?

Comment: AFTER INSERT trigger cannot affect inserted values - they are already inserted.

Comment: Nope you cannot set new. values in an after insert trigger - nor can you use auto_increment column in a generated column..AND you cannot action the table which fired the trigger in the trigger.Can you explain why you would wish to do this?

Comment: One way is to run an update after the insert..

Comment: Even though the function just returns x10 of the value, later I want to create a more complex numeric value from the auto_increment id. I understand that I cannot use After Insert and set values like this. Is it possible to update the value through a trigger. Sorry for the inconvenience, I have not much knowledge on database. This is for a POC

Comment: @Akina removed the tag. Sorry for that

Comment: ' Is it possible to update the value through a trigger.' - no

Comment: Neither triggers nor generated columns may solve this task. The only solution is post-insertion UPDATE (as single query or in stored procedure). Another solution is to remove `identifier` column at all and build needed value in retrieving query.

Comment: Thanks, will look into using the Procedure to make it work

Comment: @P.Salmon `information_schema.tables` is a view. It obtains `auto_increment` using inner function `internal_auto_increment`, and I do not know where its code may be taken. The only function parameter which looks like AI-relative is `stat.auto_increment`. I think the value is renewed only after the query execution finished and statistic renewed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trigger cannot see the value that is about to be assigned to the auto-incremented column.

Since `identifier` contains *derived* information, it might be simpler not to actually store it. A computed column is not an option, since it cannot refer to an auto-increment column. You could use a view instead:

```
create view myview (id, identifier, name, number) as
select id, id * 10, name, number from mytable
```